# How to force user to deal with the Security Warning when starting Access 2007?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, security-warning

When a user start an Access 2007 database that have macros and vba, a security warning is shown. I want the user to deal with this warning, so if the the content is't enabled, the user should not be able to use the database.

Now I use a macro named `AutoExec` (opens a form that works like a menu), and that macro is run  before the user deal with the security warning. But I want to check if the content is enabled and if not I will show a form that inform the user that they should enable the content.

So what I'm actually asking for is how do I do this:

1. If vba and macros **is not enabled** -> show form "information"
2. If vba and macros **is enabled** -> show form "start menu"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after a while I have the solution. Thanks for the answers who led me the right way.

[This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931407) from Microsoft is very helpful.

In the AutoExec-macro, I have two lines:

Line one: `Conditions: [CurrentProject].[IsTrusted]=False` and then I choose witch Form I want to open and in this case it is the "info about security warning form"

Line two: `Conditions: [CurrentProject].[IsTrusted]=True` and now open the "start menu form"

And that's all!

Comment: Just commenting - this is a good solution -- but will this code even run if isTrusted is false?

Comment: Yes, Access 2007 supports a subset of macro actions that is considered safe while in disabled mode.

Answer (score 1):

If the content is disabled, then you cannot check, since your code cannot run....

Comment: But I hope there is some way around this. If I as default show the "information"-form, and can try to run vba and if it works, it will show the "start menu"-form this may be possible. But I need to supress the error the comes up when the vba-function is called from AutoExec.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to consider a start-up form ("information"). This will show without macros.

In addition, you can run some start-up code or a macro that closes the information form and opens the main form ("start menu"), if macros are disallowed, this will not run. However, I think you may get an unsightly warning.

EDIT

Set the timer interval to say, 100 and add a little code to Information form:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
   DoCmd.Close acForm, "Information"
   DoCmd.OpenForm "start menu"    
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, thats a good idea. But when the user have accepted to run vba/macros I don't want to show the "information"-form anymore. Instead the "startmenu"-form should be showed. Any ideas?

Comment: That is exactly what I tried. And yes, I get a warning. If I can get rid of the warning, the problem is solved.

Comment: You are not going to be able to suppress the warning, or the people who write the macros it is trying to warn you about would simply suppress it....

Comment: I have tested with a timer on a start-up form, and only the standard warning appears, not the unsightly warning that occurs with an autoexec macro.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my solution -- I was just dealing with this issue.

By default, in database options have it set to open with form "notEnabled"
On this "not enabled" form, have some text, pictures, or what have you that lets the user know that he/she needs to 'enable content'.

In the *on load* event for this form, just put some VBA to open the actual form you want the user to be presented and close the "notEnabled" form.

This way, if the user opens the database without making it trusted, enabling content, they are stuck on the form that tells them how to do that. As SOON as it's trusted, the on-load event of the form will fire and redirect the user to whichever form you want, with content enabled.

If the user opens the database and already has trusted the file, they don't see the form telling them to make it trusted.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by setting the IsTrusted flag to TRUE in your AutoExec macro. See [Transitioning Your Existing Access Applications to Access 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203849.aspx) -- search for IsTrusted to get you to the heart of the explanation of how to handle it.

Comment: If macros could set the IsTrusted flag to True, it would open a security hole.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why people give suggestions that have not been tested yet. My solution is simple:

If: [CurrentProject].[IsTrusted]=False
RunMenuCommand: CloseDatabase

Else

If: [CurrentProject].[IsTrusted]=True
RunCode: (you run the code or macro you wanted to in the first place here)

This basically closes the database if the security warnings are coming on. If they are not, it opens just fine. The user that is the admin will need to decrease the macro security levels on the computer of whoever wants to access the database. This macro unlike others will actually run because it agrees with what Access wants.

You're Welcome!

Comment: CloseDatabase would make it much harder to actually enable macros.